# smbmount cifs share through alias source ip

Tags: samba, cifs

On a box having samba 3.6.x and a IPv4 number plus an alias IPv4 number, is it possible to force smblient (mount.cifs) to **use the second (alias) IP** for mounting a windows share. Something comparable to ping's -I option:

```
ping -I my_alias_ip destination_ip
```

I didn't find anything related in *man mount.cifs*.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?